# Jaxb validation error

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm getting this error while trying to de-serialize my object :

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'ObjectProp' is not complete. One of '{"http://localhost/txt/1.12/obj/domain":MapProp}' is expected.]
```

But my xml is like this :

```
<ObjectProp type="single">
   <MapProp sn="79" version="7.0">
```

...

As you ObjectProp does contain MapProp, what can be wrong, did anyone experience this before?

Comment: Do you close the MapProp tags somewhere?

Comment: Having access to the schema would be helpful. How is the ObjectProp type defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is indicating that the XML should be namespace qualified like:

```
<ObjectProp type="single">
   <MapProp xmlns="http://localhost/txt/1.12/obj/domain" sn="79" version="7.0">
      ...
   </MapProp>
</ObjectProp>
```

For more info on JAXB & Namespaces:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html